# Where do the names "First", "Business" and "Economy" class originate from?

Tags: aircraft-design

As said in the title: where do the names "First", "Business" and "Economy" class originate from? Why they didn't use the names "First", "Second" and "Third". After all it can be hard for someone not that familiar with English to find out that "Business" is ranked higher than "Economy".

Comment: It's a mere guess so only a comment: "Second/Third" class do not sound too nice, do they? It sounds better when you link it to something positively connoted like: "business". It's not "first", but it still sounds appropriate for those people who think of themselves as important businesspeople. What's the image you have when hearing "business"? The same for economy: It does not sound good to fly "third class" (like third class, when people were still separated in social classes). But to travel in an "economic" way sounds good, doesn't it? It's mere PR gags, nought more.

Comment: I think what @PatricHartmann is trying to say is that they come from the Marketing Department. They still mean `2nd` and `3rd` class, they just sound nicer.

Comment: Yes, but what is known about the introduction. Why did they pick these names and why did all airline companies used the same ones.

Comment: `why did all airline companies used the same ones`.  They don't.  "Business" is often called "club". "Economy" is often called "coach".  American airlines often call "business", "first" on two class configurations and so on.

Comment: @PatricHartmann FWIW trains in the UK have "Standard" class rather than "Second" - a change which was made in the 80s for precisely the reason you suggest.

Comment: The current names are a progression.  A satisfying explanation of how passenger classes evolved from the era of trans-oceanic ships seems to answer your question...   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_class

Comment: @NigelHarper : That's an interesting insight, thank you; so is the Wiki article.

Comment: You might try asking this on [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) as well

Comment: @Pondlife: I think double posting is against the rules on SE, but if you think the question is better migrated to the English SE, I have no objection.

Comment: It's no problem to repost on english.SE (but I would include a link back to this question). There's no option on aviation.SE to migrate to english.SE specifically so we've done this before.

Comment: @Pondlife [travel.se] might also be a good option, as they're more focused on passenger-related issues of travel.

Comment: @Simon Nonetheless, the only allowed class descriptions in an air fare is "FIRST" or "BUSINESS" or "ECONOMY" (alternatively "COACH/ECONOMY"). The wording of fare rules is constrained to the definitions published by the Air Tariff Publishing Company since nowadays all fare rules worldwide need to be understood by computers for autopricing purposes.

Comment: @Calchas Do you have a reference?  My understanding is that fares are based on letters only, e.g. "business" might be D, K or J.  Many US airlines call these classes "first", and I've had "FIRST" printed on a J class ticket.

Comment: @Simon The first letter denotes the prime booking code, or reservation booking designator. But every airline uses different groups of letters for different cabin classes (e.g., EI uses "F" for economy class, which can be confusing since almost everyone else reserves that for first class). The fare rules itself will state the class of service: see e.g. the following unrestricted "Club World" fare (J) on BA from Leeds to Miami http://pastebin.com/jsCP1u3w

Comment: @Simon but you are quite right, so if that international business class fare covers travel on AA within the USA, how do I decide which class I should book for reservations on AA? ["J", the prime code, will not be available on AA domestic flights without a business class.] To decide, we look at the Booking Code Overrides table for the fare: http://pastebin.com/E4zbuHRz You see that first I should book J if it's available—if it isn't, instead I should book F. Alas the system doesn't know which cabin that is, which is why some online agents get it wrong—we just have to keep a table up to date.

Comment: @Calchas Roger.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

They used to use those ordinal class names (first, second, third), borrowed originally from train and ocean liner class designations. British railway classes were first, second and third classes, while ocean liners typically had first, second and steerage (which itself became a derogatory term that was changed to "third class", especially as steerage evolved from a converted section of cargo space to purpose-built passenger accomodations).

The change to the modern airline classes is an example of the euphemism cycle, and occurred through the 1960s and 1970s as travel in general increased dramatically while the average income of the travelers nose-dived. In the U.S., the primary driver was the stigma of people in those sections being called "second class" or "third class" as "political correctness" started becoming a big thing with the civil rights disputes. This led to a rebranding of lower numbered classes by airlines; second class, being a popular choice for frequent flyers on corporate business seeking a compromise between the low cost of the economy section and the amenities of first class, was renamed "business class", while the main passenger cabin holding the bulk of passengers with the lowest-cost tickets (average Joes going on vacation, visiting family or just needing to get somewhere on a short travel schedule) was called "coach", "economy" or simply "standard". All of these terms have survived at least informally, but "economy" is the one most often used by the airlines to denote this service level.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong about anything, but some references would be a great addition to this answer.

Comment: Here's a blog post talking about the dysphemistic nature of the term "third class" in the context of Britain's rail system and some plans to privatize and extend service options: http://blogs.spectator.co.uk/coffeehouse/2013/10/why-do-we-cringe-at-the-term-third-class/

Comment: That doesn't really strike me as much of a reference, but if you do find something, just edit your answer to include it.

Comment: @KeithS Interesting article perhaps but it doesn't really relate to the use of these class names in aviation.